# How to get value from form field in rule?

Tags: webforms, rules

I created a webform, and a rule. The rule works on the "form submit" event.

How do I get the value from a webform field in this rule event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use - `%value[key]` means - enter filed key name, for example: `%value['first_name']`. You will find this key name by following steps:

Go to `webform -> Form components -> edit` -> you can find the entered "field key" value.